# Best way to customize JQuery UI Resizable method

Tags: jquery-ui

I modified one method of JQuery UI Resizable to achieve a centered resize. This works fine if I just link to my modified jQuery UI source. But I would like to link to the CDN hosted minified JQuery UI code and just inject the modified _respectSize method when making the call $("#selector").resizable({ .. });

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include this after bringing in jQuery UI and before you create your `resizable` widget.

```
$.ui.resizable.prototype._respectSize = function() {
    //Do your custom thing here.
};
```